# Ajax, pass already encoded value

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to pass encoded value through AJAX data but it keeps encoding it further. How can I prevent encoding in AJAX?

My ajax code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: {
            'at': ajax_params['at'],
        },
        type: form.attr("method"),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success');
        }
    });
```

Value in `ajax_params['at'] = 2%2C+4`

where 2 and 4 is value, %2C is comma and + is space. The value can be longer with multiple commas.

Current output after AJAX submit:

> at=2%252C%2B4

Expected output:

> at=2%2C+4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set `data` using a string:

```
data: "at=" + ajax_params['at'],
```

or decode it so that when it gets encoded again, it's not double-encoded:

```
data: {
    'at': decodeURIComponent(ajax_params['at'])
},
```

---

Side note: You don't need to use brackets notation and quotes for the property `at`, either in the property name in the literal or when looking it up on `ajax_params`:

```
data: {
    at: decodeURIComponent(ajax_params.at)
},
```

`at` isn't a keyword or reserved word in JavaScript (and even if it were, as of ES5 — back in 2009 — using unquoted keywords in property creation and access expressions was enabled in the language).

Comment: And how can I pass multiple rows of data as a string? Because the AJAX encoding works differently than the encoding I'm using (Django) -> 2%2C+4 after AJAX encodes is 2%2C%2B4.

Comment: ^ Got it. It's just + '&...'

Answer (score 0):

Decode it before sending

```
data: {
  at: decodeURIComponent(ajax_params['at'])
},
```